# Fetching Geolocation data to store in ionic 2 application

Tags: google-maps, typescript, geolocation, ionic2

I am trying to get Geolocation data into `coords` to store in DynamoDB in my ionic application, i keep getting an error if i follow my below code,

```
bookResource(resourceId, timeslot): Promise<void> {
let promise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.globals.displayLoader("Place...");

  let place : Place = {
    coords: google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
    userId: this.globals.getUserId(),
    userFirstName: this.globals.getUserFirstName(),
    userLastName: this.globals.getUserLastName(),
  };
  this.authClient.getClient().placesCreate(this.globals.getUserId(), place).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      place.placeId = data.placeId;
      this.places.push(place);
      resolve();
    },
    (err) => {
      reject(err);
    }
  );
});
return promise;
}
```

the `coords` value in the above code is not storing geolocation coordinates, whereas, my `userId` values are stored correctly, how do i fix this. thanks

Comment: are you trying to get current location of device?

Comment: @raj yes i am trying to get current location of device

Answer (score 0):

Native functionalities in `ionic` usually returns a `Promise` or `Observable` which you can access only inside the `success` callback. So if you are trying to save the location of the device you can use `GeoLocation` plugin from ionic. Check out [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/)

```
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
  getLocation(){
    let options = { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 50000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
    return Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((pos)=>{
    let place : Place = {
      coords: pos.coords,
      userId: this.globals.getUserId(),
      userFirstName: this.globals.getUserFirstName(),
      userLastName: this.globals.getUserLastName(),
    };
    return place;
    }).catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

then you can access location like

```
this.getLocation().then((place)=>{
  console.log(place) // you can do whatever you want with ``place`` here
     this.authClient.getClient().placesCreate(this.globals.getUserId(), place).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      place.placeId = data.placeId;
      this.places.push(place);
    },
    (err) => {
    }
  );
})
```

Comment: i have updated my code which returns a promise, could you modify the code which i have into your question, i believe your answer will work, thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution which I think would work for you. Accept it as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Run `ngOnInit` creating a function where it gets latlong values and stores its value in the database

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.map = this.initMap();
  setInterval(() => {
    this.initMap();
  });
}
```

The below is the function which is to be run `OnInit` where it returns a promise.

```
initMap(): Promise<void> {
    let promise: Promise<void> = new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        let place: Place = {
          coords: latLng,
          userId: this.globals.getUserId(),
          userFirstName: this.globals.getUserFirstName(),
          userLastName: this.globals.getUserLastName(),
        };
        let GooleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 18
        });
          this.authClient.getClient().placesCreate(this.globals.getUserId(), place).subscribe(
            (data) => {
              place.placeId = data.placeId;
              this.places.push(place);
              resolve();
            },
            (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```